# Delay between each click on a page

Tags: javascript

I'm clicking all buttons in a page, my code is

javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_54k8 _52jh _56bs _56bt');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click();  }
```

What I want is to delay between each click, suppose 5 seconds.

Could you please help me?

I've tried adding , 5000); at the end with many ways, it returns with a -

> VM1879:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Please help

Comment: Tried adding , 5000) where?

Comment: The `, 5000` presumably goes as a second parameter to `setTimeout`, which you are missing. If your above code is in a function called `a`, then you could do `setTimeout(a, 5000)`, to have `a` execute after 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm new at this, could you please write me the whole code kindly?

Comment: @StackUser We are not a free code server

Comment: Thanks for your time, whatever you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_54k8 _52jh _56bs _56bt');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { setTimeout(function() {inputs[i].click()}, 5000);  }
```

This will wait 5 seconds before each click.

Your issue was that you didnt have the `setTimeout` call which is what you would use to use the `, 5000)` syntax. It seems like you're a bit new but without the `setTimeout(` there's no function, which means the `, 5000)` makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks,
but something seems not to be right,

can you please tell me what happend?

https://image.ibb.co/i0zbPk/2017_07_27_022558.jpg

Comment: That has nothing to do with my solution, that's an error in your code. However, I think you're seeing my solution working because it's probably executing that code. Please check this as correct solution if you find it solved the problem you asked in your question.

Comment: Ok, I marked it solved.
Thank you.

but it worked before adding the  setTimeout functiong :(

Comment: Hmm.. well I can help still. Thanks for marking. From your picture it seems like something is trying to access `__tsGuarded` can you find that in your code?

Comment: Then it must be some kind of plugin you're using that's trying to access it. I'm really not sure how adding `setTimeout` to your logic changes any of that though. It just waits to call instead of calling right away. I'll post an update for you to try, let me know if that works better?

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot. I forgot to put `function() {}` in the settimeout call. Can you try what I have now? I updated original answer.

Comment: Nope, that would be me.

I didn't get a thing what you said,

Could you please re write it for me for the last time?

I need to learn a lot :(

Comment: I changed my original answer to what is there now. You should be able to copy and paste and see if it works. And don't feel bad. We've all been there. We all came from not knowing and got help from people that do.